# How to make the little guy in google map snap back to the nearest point if threw away?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

In this google map sample: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple.html
If the user dropped the little guy far away in the middle of the ocean for example, it disappears.
But in the main google map website http://maps.google.com/ If you made it show the street view, and the user dragged the guy away it get back automatically to the previous point.

What is missed in the first example to make it behave the same as the google map website?

here is the code of the sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API Example: Street View Layer</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/standard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function initialize() {
    var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573,-71.098326);
    var mapOptions = {
      center: fenway,
      zoom: 14,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    var panoramaOptions = {
      position: fenway,
      pov: {
        heading: 34,
        pitch: 10,
        zoom: 1
      }
    };
    var panorama = new  google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"),panoramaOptions);
    map.setStreetView(panorama);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div>
  <div id="pano" style="position:absolute; left:410px; top: 8px; width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, add an event listener to position_changed and use it to store the last (valid) location that pegman was dropped.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'position_changed', function() {
  // Store position
});
```

And then add an event listener to visibility_changed (which is triggered when pegman is dropped in the ocean) to set him back to the last known location:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'visible_changed', function() {
  if (panorama.getVisible() == false && last_location) {
    panorama.setPosition(last_location);
  }
});
```

Comment: I did exactly that, and I see that panorama.setPosition(last_location); is getting called with the right last_location but the map and panorama never get back, the panorama keeps blank. is there something I am still missing?

Comment: No luck here too. Pegman always snaps back. I think this happens after our attempt to set a new position.